# How can I add a link to users of an organic groups in views

Tags: views, users, organic-groups

I have a views which lists groups (I am using drupal commons distribution). I like to add a link in this view to members of that group. 
Any idea how this might be accomplished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Build a new view or block listing users and limit access to members of the users of group. Go to you current view and add a link to the new view or block.

Got to Structure>Views and add a view. Name and set to Users

Set groups fields and filter to specific group.

Change the page URL

Save

Copy url of view and go to existing view and create the link.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did the above and even added relationships but still have problems. What I am trying to do is as follows:
I have groups (course) with members (teachers). The view I have is a list of courses (with various exposed filters). 
what i like to do is to link my apply now button (global text field) to a list of teachers which are registered for that course. i.e members of that group (without showing the other teachers). 
Thanks